# JQuery ScrollTop in the middle of an animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 containers whose widths change. Inside them, I have clickable elements. When a container is clicked, it resizes in an animation. I want to make it so that when a clickable element is clicked, its container resizes and scrolls to the clicked element. Here's a fiddle that shows this: http://jsfiddle.net/w7H3M/1/

However, it scrolls to the wrong position because of the resizing. Here's the event handler for the click:

```
<div id=left>...</div>
<div id=right>...</div>

$('#left').on('click', 'a', function () {
    var node = $(this);
    $('#left').animate({
        width: 0.75 * $(document).width()
    }, 800);
    $('#right').animate({
        width: 0.25 * $(document).width()
    }, 800);

    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: node.offset().top
    }, 800);
});

$('#right').on('click', 'a', function () {
    var node = $(this);
    $('#left').animate({
        width: 0.25 * $(document).width()
    }, 800);
    $('#right').animate({
        width: 0.75 * $(document).width()
    }, 800);

    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: node.offset().top
    }, 800);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Effectively, it does not work correctly because of the animation. The offset of the node you want to show at the top of the screen will change when the div expands. To achieve what you want, you need to set the scrollTop property when the animation completes. You can achieve this using the complete handler of jQuery.animate(). I've forked your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nUADS/2/) to show you it. The only problem is that the two animationw now play one after the other instead of simultaneously.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// generate content
var str = '';
for (i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    str += '<p>' + x100(i) + '</p>';
}
$('#left').html(str);
$('#right').html(str);
// end generate content

$('#left').on('click', 'p', function () {
    var node = $(this);
    $('#left').animate({
        width: 0.75 * $(document).width(),
    }, 800, 'swing', function() {
        $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: node.offset().top}, 800);
    });
    $('#right').animate({
        width: 0.25 * $(document).width()
    }, 800);


});

$('#right').on('click', 'p', function () {
    var node = $(this);
    $('#left').animate({
        width: 0.25 * $(document).width()
    }, 800);
    $('#right').animate({
        width: 0.75 * $(document).width()
    }, 800, 'swing', function() {
        $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: node.offset().top}, 800);
    });


});
```

});